# Detect onmouseout in Google Gadget without event attribute in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, dhtml, google-gadget

I need a JavaScript method to detect when the mouse leaves an element with `id="myDiv"` within an `if()` statement.

I **cannot** use the JS `onmouseout` event embedded in my HTML.  I must be able to detect `onmouseout` inside an `if()` statement if at all possible.

Here is the basic syntax I was thinking of, but it doesn't make sense as is (and hasn't been working):

```
if(document.getElementById("myDiv").onmouseout) // if mouse leaves <div id="myDiv">
{
  //code to be executed
}
```

I prefer legit "Google Gadget JavaScript", which may be slightly different, but if you know of a JavaScript solution, you're welcome to share it!

Comment: And that doesn't work because... ?

Comment: I need a lot of things as well, but at least I try and show that I'm doing some kind of effort to be rewarded with some help ... your not!

Comment: I already have called an onmouseout for the same element, and I'm dealing within a second onmouseout from parent elements.

Comment: What exactly do you try to achieve with that if-condition? The onmouseout property would hold an event handler function.

Comment: I need a method to determine if the mouse has left an element within a function

Comment: I suppose I could call a second function if it would happen to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be used like this:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").onmouseout = function(){
    //code to be executed
}
```

Comment: What does `_gel("Div")` return?

Comment: It's the google document.getElementById().  It operates slightly differently than that though, so I don't really know!

Comment: Will be soon.  The situation isn't just "Hello World" easy, but I'm on a roll again!  Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe now I get what you mean...

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").onmouseout = function(e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    else e.cancelBubble = true;
    // code to be executed
};
```

In this way, the `onmouseout` event doesn't propagate to the ancestors of `#myDiv`.

Comment: That was smart, and nearly exactly what i need!  (my code above will integrate some of this).  My main error was a small typo :-)

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with Derek's suggestion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
<ModulePrefs title="hello world example" />
<Content type="html"><![CDATA[
<div id="myDiv">Hello, world!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
_gel("myDiv").onmouseout = function(getScroll){
_gel("myDiv").innerHTML="working!";
}
</script>
]]></Content>
</Module>
```